# How can I make a volatile Excel formula static, specifically a formula containing the TODAY function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a task log that I created at work to prioritize my daily to-do's.

In one column I've added a formula to automatically calculate Covey's quadrant numbers based on whether or not I've assigned a task as urgent or not urgent and important or less important (which populates as `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`). I also have a column to assign a due date. I want to automatically assign a due date and I wrote a formula to do so, but the `TODAY` function means that tomorrow, my due dates will change. Here is what I am looking to accomplish:

1. I want the due date to calculate automatically based on the quadrant in column G and today's date.
2. I want the due date to remain static when I open the workbook tomorrow.
3. When I enter a new task tomorrow, I want the due date to automatically calculate again using the TODAY function and then again remain static the next day, as so on and so forth.

I have been researching this topic online furiously for some time now to no avail. I have found many recommendations to use CTRL+ to automatically enter today's date into a cell, and that is not what I am looking for.

Please review my formula below and let me know if there is any way to accomplish my goals, macro, vba, formula or otherwise. Please be very detailed in your directions as I am just learning about macro and vba.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E4),"",IF([@QUADRANT]=1, TODAY()+1,IF([@QUADRANT]=2, TODAY()+7,IF([@QUADRANT]=3, TODAY()+3, IF([@QUADRANT]=4, TODAY()+30)))))
```

Comment: Could you just copy that column at the end of the day and paste it into a new column using paste.special: values? That way you have the original column ready for tomorrow... just a suggestion as I don’t know what your data looks like...

Comment: Write a VBA function that returns the required due date. Then in the worksheet's OnChange event, watch for the user to enter the letter `d` into your Due Date column. When this happens, run the function and replace the cell's value with the calculated date. Then any time you want a static, but correctly calculated due date, type "d" and it will be entered for you.

Comment: I've modified my ANSWER, find two solutions, will help you to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**I would like to suggest TWO Solutions, to achieve the Goal.**

**Solution 1:**

*Use these VBA codes as Module. **First** will convert the Current Date in cell A1 into a Static Date Value while Saving the Workbook and **Second** Macro will Convert the Static Date Value into Volatile.*

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    With Sheet1.Range("A1")
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     With Sheet1.Range("A1")
        .Value = "=Today()"
    End With

    End Sub
```

**Solution 2:**

*In place of two different Macros you can create a **Toggle Button** to Convert the Volatile Date into Static and again to Volatile Date value.*

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     If CommandButton1.Caption = "Convert Static" Then

      With Sheet1.Range("A1")
      .Value = .Value
      End With

   CommandButton1.Caption = "Convert Volatile"

   ElseIf CommandButton1.Caption = "Convert Volatile" Then

    With Sheet1.Range("A1")
            .Value = "=Today()"
        End With

  CommandButton1.Caption = "Convert Static"
  End If

  End Sub
```

**NB:** Follow these steps to accomplish the Job.

1. **In the sheet 1 where you execute your Formula, in Cell A1 write this Formula = Today().**
2. **For the solution 1**, Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA Editor, find the "Microsoft Excel Objects".
3. Right Click the Mouse on it, find Insert then Module.
4. Copy & Paste both the Macros.

**For Solution 2**, follow these steps.

1. In Sheet 1, Click the *Developer Tab*, find Design Mode, left to it is Insert.
2. Find ActiveX Controls, the first is Command Button, Click it and draw the button in blank area.
3. Right Click the Command button, Find Properties, Find Caption and change it to Convert Static.
4. Return to Sheet, double click the Command button, VBA editor will be open.
5. Copy and Paste the VBA Code, go to File menu, hit Close and Return to Excel.
6. Again click the Design button on top to turn it deactivate.
7. Click the Command Button, will change Volatile Date value in Cell A1 to Static, and change the Caption of Command Button also to, Convert Volatile.
8. Click it again when you want to change Cell value A1 to Static.

*Remember, on your each Click the Macro will convert Date in A1 cell Volatile to Static to Volatile.*

**Note,** *in YOUR FORMULA use Cell A1 instead of TODAY().*

You are free to write =Today() Formula in any BLANK CELL but don't forget to modify the Cell Address accordingly.

*I'm sure this help you.*

Comment: My comment gave your solution 2 a while ago....

Comment: Sorry @SolarMike,,, i've had not noticed it and mine is lil different, I suggested to Paste in the Same Cell.

Comment: So, your way actually removes the formulae so it won't work tomorrow...

Comment: @SolarMike, Yes, suggested 3 options are Converting Today() Volatile to Static and it was the OP's demand, since Static Formula Never Updates.

Comment: So you did not understand « and so on and so forth » ie the OP would like it to continue working tomorrow in the fashion it has been designed - you want it to work once then never again - it needs to work once each day and save that day’s information THEN be ready to repeat the next day...

Comment: @SolarMike, let me modify and add Cyclic method, meanwhile you suggest how to fix the issue, will help OP.

Comment: @SolarMike, find the modified Solution, will solve the issue in the way OP has demanded.

Comment: Hello all, Thank you for your help with my issue. I am considering how solution one will work for my purposes. If my due date formula points to "D1" (that is the blank cell I am using instead of "A1"), and it becomes static when I save the workbook, then tomorrow it will become volatile again when I reopen the workbook and my due date will change. Isn't that right? What I would like is for the due dates for the tasks that I create today to stay static tomorrow, and for tasks that I enter tomorrow to calculate using the formula and then stay static the following day.

Comment: For the second solution, if I toggle the cell to volatile, then all the due dates will change I think, not just the due dates for new tasks that I have entered. Correct me if I am misinterpreting your solutions.

Comment: Give me some time since  it's a OLDER POST let me check the question again, soon I'll back to you.

Comment: @BriannaCamps, Please  use a cell Which has DATE value, otherwise how these Macros will work,,, I've picked CELL A1 ,, you are free  to use any other Cell like D1, but always remember the Cell must Current date.Please read my both Solutions carefully, first  one generates Cyclic effect when you save & open the WBK.  Second one will convert Static to volatile on CLICK,, since it's  toggle button. Use which one is useful to you, both are working.