# How to insert a timestamp based on a check box or button in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I've been working on a workbook for personal use for a while now and one of the sheets tracks my hours. My hours are all input manually and calculated automatically. What I would like to accomplish is linking a cell to a check box or button and recording the time the box was checked. For example when clock in, I would check a box or press a button and the time would be recorded, but not updated. I'm not very familiar with macros or VBA's yet so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I've created a formula based on if the boxes are checked **and** the current time is after the times described in the *Clock In* and *Clock Out* columns. 
This is the formula in cell R14: `=IF(AND(AND(N14,NOW()>O14),AND(P14,NOW()>=Q14)),Q14-O14,NOW()-O14)`
The check boxes in N14 and P14 are linked to the cells they reside in and the values in cells O14 and Q14 are just time values formatted to display the clock in date and time
[This is what I'm working with so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMs4u.png)

Comment: To make the Time Static,, **Copy** the Cell and from **Paste Special** Click **Value** & finish with **Ok**. But it's tedious job when you are suppose to enter Time in Range of Cells instead of a Cell or a few.                                                                                               Check this link if you can handle simple VBA https://superuser.com/questions/1287989/how-can-i-make-a-volatile-excel-formula-static-specifically-a-formula-containin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any example on how you want it to look, or how the current tracking is done, I just made some kind of time tracker, tracking seconds.
So I did a timer thusly: 
Add a button, and 00:00:00 as the time in cell where you want to keep track of time.
In my case this is the cell `C2`, I call this the `timerPos`. 
I then use cell `A1` or any other spare cell to keep track of time and if I'm recording, I call this the `trackerPos`.
Then when I press my button, this is how it will look initially:

[image: Press Timer]

When I'm done keeping track of time, I press the button again. The tracker is cleared, and the timer is updated:

[image: Press again]

Now, the most important part; the code for the button.

```
Sub timer()
Dim timeL As Long, timerPos As Range, trackerPos As Range

Set timerPos = Range("C2")
Set trackerPos = Range("A1")

If trackerPos.Value = "" Then
    trackerPos.Value = Now
Else
    timeL = Abs(Now - trackerPos.Value) * 86400
    timerPos.Value = DateAdd("s", timeL, timerPos.Value)
    timerPos.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
    trackerPos.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Usage:
The variables `timerPos` and `trackerPos` can be easily changed to suit your needs on where you want to keep the timer.

The first line of the `Else` part converts the difference in time between the current time and the time in the tracker. 
The second line adds the time to the timer. The third line keeps formatting from showing dates when going beyond 24 hours.

**Edit**

If we want to limit the amount of time recorded for each recording to 8 hours, we only need to add a small `If`.
8 Hours is 28800 seconds, so we check if timeL is larger than this number, and if so, set it to this number.

```
    timeL = Abs(Now - trackerPos.Value) * 86400
    If timeL > 28800 Then
        timeL = 28800
    End If
    timerPos.Value = DateAdd("s", timeL, timerPos.Value)
```

While we are at it, I added some changing of color and text to the button, for visual aid that the timer is ticking.

```
Sub timer()
Dim timeL As Long, timerPos As Range, trackerPos As Range, button As Variant

Set button = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1") 'Make sure this is the right button
Set timerPos = Range("C2")
Set trackerPos = Range("A1")

If trackerPos.Value = "" Then
    trackerPos.Value = Now
    button.Characters.Text = "Stop timer"
    button.Font.ColorIndex = 3
Else
    timeL = Abs(Now - trackerPos.Value) * 86400
    If timeL > 28800 Then
        timeL = 28800
    End If
    timerPos.Value = DateAdd("s", timeL, timerPos.Value)
    timerPos.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
    trackerPos.Value = ""
    button.Text = "Start timer"
    button.Font.ColorIndex = 50
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information! However, I'm sorry I didn't really provide the question with examples of what I'm looking for. The code you've shared with me works, but I am wondering if you can add something in the code for the button, if the timer goes past 8 hours, or 08:00:00, it stops, and retains, 8 hours. Our timekeeping system tracks us as having 8 hours exactly, so long as we are here 7 minutes prior to the beginning of our shift and clock out no earlier than 7 minutes before the end of our shift. Thanks

Comment: That's no problem. Do you want to limit the time recorded, or the total, or both?

Comment: This will work perfect in the table I plan to use for more accurate timekeeping. In the midst of all this confusion and research, I have come up with a much more simple solution than code, but the button method will be quicker and more efficient on a large scale. Thanks.